Purpose of Low(String)?
I was tracing some character encoding code and found this in System.SysUtils
function TEncoding.GetBytes(const S: string): TBytes;
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := GetByteCount(S);
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  GetBytes(S, Low(S), Length(S), Result, 0, Low(S));
end;

What does Low(S) do here?
The overloaded GetBytes() that gets called here is:
function TEncoding.GetBytes(const S: string; CharIndex, CharCount: Integer;
  const Bytes: TBytes; ByteIndex: Integer; const StringBaseIndex: Integer): Integer;

This has a somewhat cryptic comment:

// StringBaseIndex : Low(string) on caller's context



https://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.php?Name=Low

Low(S) returns the lowest index of the array/string, i.e. 1. As to why Low(S) is used, and not 1 hardcoded, my guess is that this code was written when (previous to Delphi 10.4) the Delphi compilers for mobile by default used 0-based indexing for strings, while the Windows compiler used 1-based indexing. Then Low(S) worked for both cases. See also https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi)

I would use LOW(Result) instead of 0 in the parameters. Just to be consistent...

The built-in function LOW() returns the lower index of an indexable item. For a STRING, this is always 1 in the most recent version, but a few versions back, this would be 0 on mobile platforms, so the use of LOW() would allow you to make code that would compile in all platforms, regardless of target.
For clarity, you should always use LOW() (and HIGH()) when iterating over the valid indices of an indexable item, even though you might know (or think you know) what the LOW and/or HIGH value is. It's just safer to let the compiler determine it for you.
I have seen constructs like this:
FOR I:=0 TO HIGH(Arr) DO ...

and my question is always, why they use HIGH() and then omits LOW() - it makes no sense to me.
So - my advice is to always do this:
FOR I:=LOW(Arr) TO HIGH(Arr) DO ...

regardless of what you know (or think you know - qua the change of LOW(STRING) from 0 to 1 in recent time).
And, when iterating over all characters in a STRING, either use:
FOR C IN Str DO ...

or:
FOR I:=LOW(Str) TO HIGH(Str) DO ...

HIGH(Str) is the same as LENGTH(Str) in modern compilers, but when LOW(Str) was 0, then HIGH(Str) equals LENGTH(Str)-1.
Using LOW() and HIGH() also clearly illustrates your intent, namely that you are iterating over all the valid indices of the item.

I guess there's no performance difference between 1 to Length(Str) and Low(Str) to High(Str)? Or is one slightly faster than the other?

@AmigoJack Well, Low() and (High() will take some CPU cycles, with a good optimizing compiler only once though.

@AmigoJack: That question is a great demonstration of the tendency to worry about premature optimization. When the entirety of your code is so performant that you need to worry about this sort of thing, you're the world's greatest coder and should have a statue erected in your honor. I'd suspect that there are a few thousand other places in code that would be more suitable to be concerned about than the performance difference between for 0 and  for Low(), especially since Delphi's compiler evaluates the loop expression only once when the loop starts.

Low() and High() are compiler intrinsics. They introduce no overhead whatsoever, but use compiler magic.

@AmigoJack: Like Johan says, the LOW and HIGH are evaluated at compile time (when possible), and HIGH(Str) compiles to the same code as LENGTH(Str) (in modern compilers)
